# How to reference in Android Studio some colors

Tags: android

I'm just started to use Android Studio and i got a lot issues, and one of them is because i'm trying to reference from my Style.xml to my page resource Colors.xml i just create, but when i'm trying to "call" the color name i cant find,maybe i have to do something to recognize the resouce file?
Style.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@Colors/myColor</item>
```

Colors.xml

```
<Color name="MyColor">#00000</Color>
```

I've been trying this all day, and nothing,how i can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try lowercase. `<color name="myColor">#0000FF</color>` and then `@color/myColor`.

Comment: i tryed to use Material Design but doesn't work! when u trying to use a Toolbar [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) my preview screen in Android Project got issues like 
"Rendering Problems" "The following classes could not be instantiated:" i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

Names are case sensitive and you also have to change `@Colors` by `@color`. You should have

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/MyColor</item
```

Comment: this is a problem.... when i create a Resource Page called by "Color.xml" i just cant call form my Style.. he dont even show the current color in the left side